# Oracle sql - aggregates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have the following data set:

```
CUST_ORD_NO       ITEM       STATUS
5451104         100004132   Fulfilled   
5451104         100182935   Unfulfilled   
5451105         100004132   Fulfilled   
5451105         100182935   Fulfilled
```

I want to show result as:

```
CUST_ORD_NO  STATUS
5451104      Unfulfilled
5451105      Fulfilled
```

If the order has any Item has Status of Unfulfilled, it should say as Unfulfilled
If the order has all the Item as Fulfilled, it should say as Fulfilled

Answer (score 2):

Take the `MAX` of the status column by cust_ord_no.

```
SELECT cust_ord_no, MAX(status) AS status
FROM t
GROUP BY cust_ord_no;
```

Comment: Clean solution.